# TeeInputStream and PipedStream does not work in any case

Tags: java, io, java-io, apache-commons-io

I run into a problem while "cloning" an InputStream.

This does not work:

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myResource");
```

But this works:

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/afas.cfg"));
```

My code is:

```
// Create a piped input stream for one of the readers.
PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();

// Create a tee-splitter for the other reader.(from apache commons io)
TeeInputStream tee = new TeeInputStream(is, new PipedOutputStream(in));

// Create the two buffered readers.
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tee));
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

// Do some interleaved reads from them.
System.out.println("One line from br1:");
System.out.println(br1.readLine());
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Two lines from br2:");
System.out.println(br2.readLine());
System.out.println(br2.readLine());
System.out.println();

System.out.println("One line from br1:");
System.out.println(br1.readLine());
System.out.println();
```

The problem occurs at the first `br1.readLine()` call. It just get stuck at `PipedInputStream.awaitSpace()` and is in an endless loop.

Are the PipedStreams only for threads? Meaning that when writing to the  PipedOutputStreams the PipedInputStream would "wake up"

What do i have to do to get this work in any case?

Comment: Yes, PipedStreams need to be in different threads.

Comment: But why does it work if the InputStream if I create the InputStream directly via `new FileInputStream(...) ?`

Comment: Your code looks a bit iffy. Are you sure you're constructing all the streams as you intend to?

Comment: It is just an example, similar to this http://java-success.blogspot.de/2013/05/java-io-and-decorator-and-proxy-design.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a misuse of piped streams. They are intended to be used by different threads. They will not work as you are using them here, because there is a 4k buffer and the writer blocks when it fills. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html):

> Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended, as it may deadlock the thread.

Personally I have never encountered a valid use for these piped streams since May 1997. I used one once back then and took it out immediately in favour of a queue.